# hex2bin($var) error : Input string must be hexadecimal string

Tags: php, string, int, hex, bin

Hello here it is small code to convert string to hex and reverse.

With this We haven't error string to hex :

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['upload']) ) // si formulaire soumis
{
    $content_dir = 'tmpcipher/'; // dossier où sera déplacé le fichier
    $tmp_file = $_FILES['fichier']['tmp_name'];
    if( !is_uploaded_file($tmp_file) )
    {

    }
    // on vérifie maintenant l'extension
    $type_file = $_FILES['fichier']['type'];
    // on copie le fichier dans le dossier de destination
    $name_file = $_FILES['fichier']['name'];

    if( !move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $content_dir . $name_file) )
    {

    }
    $name_file2 = $_FILES['fichier']['name'];
    $hex = bin2hex(file_get_contents($content_dir . $name_file2));
    unlink($content_dir . $name_file2);
    $myfile2 = fopen($content_dir . $name_file2 . "2" , "w");
    $myfileurl = $content_dir . $name_file2 . "2";
    fwrite($myfile2, $str);
    fclose($myfile2);
    $myfile3 = $content_dir . $name_file2 . "2";
    if (file_exists($myfile3)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($myfile3));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($myfile3));
    readfile($myfile3);
}
}
?>
```

Reverse, with that we have an error :

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['upload']) ) // si formulaire soumis
{
    $content_dir = 'tmpcipher/'; // dossier où sera déplacé le fichier
    $tmp_file = $_FILES['fichier']['tmp_name'];
    if( !is_uploaded_file($tmp_file) )
    {

    }
    // on vérifie maintenant l'extension
    $type_file = $_FILES['fichier']['type'];
    // on copie le fichier dans le dossier de destination
    $name_file = $_FILES['fichier']['name'];

    if( !move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $content_dir . $name_file) )
    {

    }
    $str0 = file_get_contents($content_dir . $name_file); //HEXADECIMAL CONTENT 
$hexstr1 = hex2bin("73616c7574"); //WORK
$hexstr2 = hex2bin($str0); //ERROR
    $name_file = substr($name_file,0,-1);
    $myfile2 = fopen($content_dir . $name_file, "w");
    fwrite($myfile2, $str0);
    fclose($myfile2);
    $filectohex = file_get_contents($content_dir . $name_file);
    $myfile3 = $content_dir . $name_file;
    if (file_exists($myfile3)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($myfile3));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($myfile3));
    readfile($myfile3);
}
}
?>
```

php_error_log : [25-Jan-2015 00:34:25 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  hex2bin(): Input string must be hexadecimal string in C:\xampp\htdocs\dec.php on line 47

When I take the string content of $str0 and I do hex2bin with, it works.
I don't know if PHP consider that my var is integer, please give me the solution :)

Thanks :D

[SOLVED] : Write the variable that you want to convert to ascii (hexadecimal content, and then convert to ascii the content of this file (must be hexadecimal).

```
$hex2bin($str0); ---> 
$myfile2 = fopen($content_dir . $name_file, "w");
fwrite($myfile2, $str0);
fclose($myfile2);
$myfile2path = $content_dir . $name_file;
$bin = hex2bin(file_get_contents($myfile2path));
```

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar issue while writing content of a file into another file. I then read the new file.
I had the message "not an hexadecimal string" when trying to convert an hex string to hex.

PHP appended a "00" (as a non printable character, thus not recognized as a "normal" string) on the end of every frame when he wrote the file.

To fix this, I sent the following instead of the original frame :

```
$trame1_substring=substr($trame1,0,strlen($trame1)-2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You write `$str` to the file, instead of `$hex`. The file is empty. You read an empty string, and `hex2bin('')` gives an error. It is in this piece of code:

```
// below you define $hex
$hex = bin2hex(file_get_contents($content_dir . $name_file2));
unlink($content_dir . $name_file2);
$myfile2 = fopen($content_dir . $name_file2 . "2" , "w");
$myfileurl = $content_dir . $name_file2 . "2";
// but here you write $str
fwrite($myfile2, $str);
```

You could have found this by simply echoing the content of `$str0`:

> echo "The content of str0 is [$str0]\n"

Comment: Nop, you don't understand, $str0 is the content of a file, this file is an hexadecimal content (by bin2hex), the error is on the : hex2bin($str0), when I write in the output file $str0 I have the content of my input file, When I write in my input file hex2bin($str0) so $hexstr2 (error on php_error_log), I have a space character.

Comment: I wasn't talking about `$str0`, I was talking about `$str`, which is a different variable in your first piece of code.

Comment: Ohoh I understand what you mean, but i cut a short piece of code, $str is defined by it, there's no problem with the first piece of code, I solved my problem by writing $str0 in a file (hexadecimal content) and then hex2bin(file_get_content(filecontains$str0)); $myfile2 = fopen($content_dir . $name_file, "w");
 fwrite($myfile2, $str0);
 fclose($myfile2);
 $myfile2path = $content_dir . $name_file;
 $bin = hex2bin(file_get_contents($myfile2path));
 $myfile4 = fopen($content_dir . $name_file . "t", "w");
 $myfile4path = $content_dir . $name_file . "t";
 fwrite($myfile4, $bin);
 fclose($myfile4);